# System.NotImplementedException Exception

Tags: wpf

I got the following Design time exception for my control in WPF

System.NotImplementedException
The method or operation is not implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means you have stubbed out a method but not actually provided an implementation.  This exception is inserted by Visual Studio for method stubs.